# Why are spaces delimiting, instead of FPAT

Tags: regex, awk

I'm attempting to split strings delimited by `','` except where the `','` is in a substring enclosed by brackets. Modifying other solutions here and examples in the docs I tried this test:

```
awk -v FPAT='([^,]+)|(\([^\))+\))' '{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", $i)
    }                     
}' <<< 'one two (1one), three four (3three, 4four), five six, seven eight, nine ten eleven (8ten)'
one
two
(1one),
three
four
(3three,
4four),
five
six,
seven
eight,
nine
ten
eleven
(8ten)
```

The **FPAT** isn't overriding the default delimiter as I expected. so clearly I'm missing something.

The output I want is:

```
one two (1one),
three four (3three, 4four),
five six,
seven eight, 
nine ten eleven (8ten)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `gnu grep`:

```
s='one two (1one), three four (3three, 4four), five six, seven eight, nine ten eleven (8ten)'
grep -oP '\s*\K([^,(]*\([^)]*\))*[^,]*(,|$)' <<< "$s"
```

```
one two (1one),
three four (3three, 4four),
five six,
seven eight,
nine ten eleven (8ten)
```

If you don't have `gnu grep` then you may use

```
grep -oE '([^,(]*\([^)]*\))*[^,]*(,\s*|$)' <<< "$s"
```

Which will leave trailing spaces after comma.

For [regex explanation see this demo](https://regex101.com/r/COMj2b/1).

Comment: Thanks, this gives me a usable work around. However I'd also like to know how I could have used awk.

Comment: That regex demo looks very useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your code does not work because,

1. `([^,]+)|(\([^\))+\))` is an invalid regex, it has an unmatched `[` in it,
2. You say you're using mawk, but it doesn't support FPAT.

---

Here is the FPAT solution I've come up with

```
$ cat file
one two (1one), three four (3three, 4four), five six, seven eight, nine ten eleven (8ten)
$
$ awk -v FPAT='[^,(]*(\\([^)]*\\))?(, |$)' '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) print $i }' file
one two (1one),
three four (3three, 4four),
five six,
seven eight,
nine ten eleven (8ten)
```

Explanation of `FPAT` variable:

- `[^,(]*` matches any number of non-comma, non-parenthesis chars,
- `\\([^)]*\\)` matches any number of non-parenthesis chars surrounded by parentheses,

  - Putting this in `(...)?` makes this match optional.
- `(, |$)` means matched field should end with a comma followed by a space, or it should be the last field in the line.

---

And here is how to do it in mawk

```
mawk '{ gsub(/[^,(]*(\([^)]*\))?, /, "&\n") }1'  file
```

---

sed could be used as well for this particular case

```
sed 's/[^,(]*\(([^)]*)\)\?, /&\n/g'  file
```

Comment: This does the same as my original output on my system (mawk 1.3.3). What version are you on?

Comment: gawk 4.2.1, I'm gonna check out mawk now

Comment: Oh! mawk doesn't support FPAT ok - that explains why even fixing my regex didn't work. Thank you! Your sed solution gives the required result, but not your mawk solution. The latter is also splitting when the comma occurs inside brackets.

Comment: Yep, you're welcome.  I've noticed it and fixed 5 mins ago, it still doesn't work??

Comment: YES! the mawk version also works now. Your FPAT regex explanation is very useful for future reference also. My reputation is still low, so my upvote isn't counted unfortunately. Cheers.

Comment: This has helped me a great deal! +1 Thank You